# adding an image component to Table cell by overidding `createCell`

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I am using LWUIT and showing data with `Table`, say, flight information!
Instead of writing air companies with text I just like to replace them with icons.
So, I need to override `protected Component createCell(Object value, final int row, final int column, boolean editable)` method of `Table`.

This is how I've implemented:

## Initializing

```
imgAln[i]=null;
try {
    imgAln[i] = Image.createImage(strPathToImage[i]);
                        //e.g /uta.png,/somonair.png and so on
    lAln[i] = new Label(imgAln[i]);
} catch (IOException e) { }
```

## Creating Table object

```
Table table = new Table(model) {
    protected Component createCell(Object value, final int row, 
               final int column, boolean editable) {
        final Component c = super.createCell(value, row, column, editable);
        if (column == 6) {
            return lAln[value];  //it does not work here 
        }
    }
};
```

need help to add Image to table cell!!!

Is there any example??? links are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your `createCell(...)` implementation is that it does not return the `super.createCell(...)` when the `column is not 6`. Also your array of labels (`lAln`) may not be properly created. Try my implementation below, but make sure you store the appropriate image name in the table models' `column 0`.

**This should solve it:**

```
TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
    new String[]{"Uneditable", "Editable", "CheckBox", "Multiline"}, 
    new Object[][]{
        {"/animations.png", "", new Boolean(false), "Multi-line text\nright here"},
        {"/buttons.png", "", new Boolean(true), "Further text that\nspans lines"},
        {"/dialogs.png", "", new Boolean(true), "No span"},
        {"/fonts.png", "", new Boolean(false), "Spanning\nFor\nEvery\nWord"},
    });

Table table = new Table(model) {
    protected Component createCell(Object value, final int row, 
                    final int column, boolean editable) {
        if (row != -1 && column == 0) {
            try {
                            //In my case Column 0 store the resource path names
                return new Label(Image.createImage((String)value));     
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return super.createCell(value, row, column, editable);
    }
};
```

*NOTE:* If you see the names instead of images in column 0 it means the image path is incorrect, fix it to see the images.

Did you manage to have a look at `TableLayoutDemo.java` in project **`LWUITDemo`**? If i remember it correct, this comes bundled download package `LWUIT1.5.zip` (or you can always google it).

Let me know if you need more specific help.

Comment: Thank you very much Vimal! Perfect working example! It works! As for demo example that you recommended me, I now looking over it! Thanks! here is a screen shot http://www.flickr.com/photos/67246820@N08/6525971703/in/photostream

Comment: Pic looking great, happy that it worked :) The path to the lwuit demo is [here](http://java.net/projects/lwuit/sources/svn/show/LWUIT_1_5/Apps/LWUITDemo?rev=1642)

Comment: I have one more question for you! how to set utf-8 string to lwuit form's title? I set `fMain=new Form("блабла");` and when i run this, the form's title will be empty! Does it support `utf-8`? If yes, how to set utf-8 string to it's title?

Comment: Try [this](http://markmail.org/search/?q=%22Button+with+UTF-8+text%22#query:%22Button%20with%20UTF-8%20text%22+page:1+mid:ijdhvdvi6wvqa7nz+state:results) link, it should solve your problem.